# Create a file with a streaming interface

Tags: files, devices

I was trying to create a file with a streaming interface just like /dev/random. Basically, I provide some initial contents to the file, and when a program reads from the file, it consumes some bytes, so others can only read from the rest of the file. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You mean a pipe?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are describing a *named pipe*, also known as a FIFO.

```
bash-4p4$ mkfifo mypipe

bash-4.4$ ( dd if=/dev/random of=mypipe ) &
[1] 37688

bash-4.4$ hexdump -C mypipe | head -n 2
00000000  e0 de 4a 6e 48 63 aa 25  21 77 89 85 53 fd 36 57  |..JnHc.%!w..S.6W|
00000010  c3 be 55 f3 15 00 6b 44  64 27 c4 d8 8c 7d de d5  |..U...kDd'...}..|

bash-4.4$ hexdump -C mypipe | head -n 2
00000000  dd ff 66 1d 15 f2 0b 55  ee 94 f2 f1 96 60 e9 8a  |..f....U.....`..|
00000010  a0 b9 9d 1d 08 22 0b 33  ad dc 94 c1 61 49 e0 1b  |.....".3....aI..|

bash-4.4$ hexdump -C mypipe | head -n 2
00000000  82 7e 99 20 30 65 b9 eb  35 bd 6f 6b b6 bf 7e 2a  |.~. 0e..5.ok..~*|
00000010  5e c2 97 b4 e6 47 be 85  43 ab d7 00 be 86 f2 ae  |^....G..C.......|

bash-4.4$ hexdump -C mypipe | head -n 2
00000000  3c 22 69 e2 95 64 6f 4e  e4 3d 69 8c eb 68 c7 2f  |<"i..doN.=i..h./|
00000010  b5 76 4d 81 59 db 06 9b  e7 97 85 01 db c3 e0 7b  |.vM.Y..........{|

bash-4.4$ kill %1
bash-4.4$
[1]+  Terminated              ( dd if=/dev/random of=mypipe )

bash-4.4$ rm mypipe
```